# How to store 2 records on the same column at different times?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Im trying to store 2 DATETIME records alongside each other using buttons that will be clicked at different times. At the moment the records just store under each other, as shown below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     clock_in     |     clock_out    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     14:50:05     |     00:00:00     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     00:00:00     |     14:52:45     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Id like the records to store like this, when both buttons are clicked, or if one button is clicked twice (Once for "clock_in" and again for "clock_out"):

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     clock_in     |     clock_out    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     14:50:05     |     14:52:45     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     09:12:40     |     13:32:33     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Code Sample:

```
<h2>Clock In</h2>
 <form action="" method="REQUEST">
   <button name="click" class="click">Clock In!</button>
 </form>
<h2>Clock Out</h2>
 <form action="" method="REQUEST">
   <button name="click2" class="click2">Clock Out!</button>
 </form>

<?php
 require('db.php');

 if(isset($_REQUEST['click']))
 {
    $clock_in = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');;
    echo "Clocked in at: " . $clock_in . "<br>";

    $query = "INSERT into `records` (clock_in)
   VALUES ('$clock_in')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 }

 if(isset($_REQUEST['click2']))
 {
    $clock_out = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');;
    echo "Clocked out at: " . $clock_out . "<br>";

    $query = "INSERT into `records` (clock_out)
  VALUES ('$clock_out')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hint:  You need an `update` if you want to change a column in an existing row.  A better solution might be just to record the clicks and then bring the data together when you are querying.

Comment: I also don't know what's the purpose of this code but you should also check if that "user" can make that kind of requests and also secure those queries against SQL injection.

Comment: Code purpose is to store DATETIME records when users "clock in" and "clock out" of work, whenever each button is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, where to begin, 
1st: Select POST or GET, better POST.
2nd: Use Filter, that why use POST/GET not REQUEST.
3rd: Why you initialize date() with Y-m-d, when you use only the time?
4th: Use Prepared Statements. When you write Var in SQL and don't change it, when you create Production Software, you can use MySQLi how much you can, you are hacked in seconds. A Problem where I see, you can Click out without Click in. You need a little JS and Ajax, so you can Disable Button Click_out and Enable it when Click_in is clicked. So you can do it with "INSERT" and "SELECT" (to check if click_in in db is set) AND "UPDATE".

```
<?php
$clockIn = "";
$clockOut = "";
$id = null;
$anyGodLikeOutPut = "";
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timetrack;charset=utf8;", "username", "passwort");

if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "click")) {
    $clockIn = date('H:i:s');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `records`(`ID`, `clock_in`) VALUES (NULL, :cin)";
    $PDOStatement = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    $PDOStatement->bindParam(":cin", $clockIn, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($PDOStatement->execute()) {
        $anyGodLikeOutPut = "Your result: " . $clockIn;
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("MYSQL Error: " . implode(",", $PDOStatement->errorInfo()));
    }
}
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "click2") && filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "id")) {
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $clockOut = date('H:i:s');
    $sql = "UPDATE `records` SET `ID` = :id, `clock_out`= :cout";
    $PDOStatement = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    $PDOStatement->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $PDOStatement->bindParam(":cout", $clockOut, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($PDOStatement->execute()) {
        $anyGodLikeOutPut = "Your result: " . $clockOut;
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("MYSQL Error: " . implode(",", $PDOStatement->errorInfo()));
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head></head>
<body>
<?= $anyGodLikeOutPut; ?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <h2>Clock In</h2>
    <button name="click" class="click">Clock In!</button>
</form>
<form action="" method="post">
    <h2>Clock Out</h2>
    <button name="click2" class="click2">Clock Out!</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id; ?>">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store ID of first date somewhere. Maybe hidden input. Then if hidden input is set you should run an UPDATE query on that specific row with that specific ID.

Comment: Will i not have to constantly be changing the specific ID in the code, as ID's will be different everytime?

Comment: Yes, ID will be different every time. That's why you should store it somewhere. If it's safe you can store it in URL like: youraddress.com/script.php?id=5 or in that hidden input. So after first input (clock_in) you'll get ID and for clock_out you have to update that ID.